# The result of PEView and HxD is different. Is it possible?

Tags: reverse-engineering

The result of PEView and HxD is  different. Is it possible?
I thought it should be same because it is raw data.

In PEveiw:
[image: In PEveiw]

In HxD:
[image: In HxD]

Comment: Do the two program's view of the file differ again, a little bit further down?  That changed byte is part of a field that indicates where the PE header is located.  You should find the bytes `50 45 00 00` later in the file - at offset 000000F0 according to PEview, offset 000000F8 according to HxD.

Answer (score 1):

The correct value is `F8' according to all my tools on Windows 10, including PEView 0.9.9.  Are you running both tools in the exact same environment?  In a VM?

F8 is part of the `e_lfanew` field value in the DOS header, i.e. offset to the new executable header. In layman's terms, it points to the actual NT header (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS in PEView). `lfa` means `long file address`. It is a 32-bit (DWORD) relative virtual address (RVA) value. IMAGE_NT_HEADERS is located after the DOS stub and the Rich Signature header if one exists (it does in notepad.exe).

Of interest, using PEView and notepad.exe on a Windows 7 32-bit VN, the value displayed is `D8` due to a different Rich Signature header.

Comment: I run this on host window10 not in VM. Not only e_lfanew value, but DOS stub values and PE header start point are different. weird

Comment: I get the correct values in both tools on Windows 10.  Please add the DOS stub values for both tools to your question so I can have a look at the differences,

Comment: I edit image file which showing stub code. Thank you for your  attention!